# Delete all cookies in a loop

Tags: c#, firefox, cookies, file-io

I need to make a program with C# (or any other language if it's preferred) that works in a loop, and deletes Firefox cookies if there are any.

Right now, this is the code I have:

```
        while (true) {
            System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\Users\ameir\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\f7da5usz.default\cookies.sqlite");
            try
            {
                fi.Delete();
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

But that does not work, because the file is being used by Firefox.

Comment: What is your loop's exit condition?

Comment: @RobertColumbia it doesnt have any. its supposed to be a simple program that works, until it is exited out of

Comment: What are you looking for the code to do? Do you want it to close Firefox programamtically? Are there certain types of files you want to delete (your example is a cookie database, not a cookie itself...). What should happen if it can't delete a cookie?

Comment: @RobertColumbia basically, there is one cookie that tracks the amounts of login, once it reaches 3, it locks. i can delete the cookie in firefox, but that slows down the process of bruteforce. I need to delete that single cookie everytime it is set. if there is a better way to do it rather than deleting the file, that would be fantastic!

Comment: @robert it's 100% legal by the way it is being hosted on a local server.

Comment: I didn't say it was illegal. It looks like what you are trying to do is have an application constantly running and checking for the presence of a Firefox cookie file, and any time it finds such a file, it deletes it. Is that right?

Comment: @RobertColumbia yes, but i have trouble because the file is being used by firefox when i need to delete it.